# Resource handler returned message: "Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObject for

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I keep getting this error when running `cdk deploy my_stack`:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObject for deploymentbucket-xxxyyyzzz/local_development_resources_f123_abc/artifact. S3 Error Code: AccessDenied. S3 Error Message: Access Denied (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 403, Request ID: abcd-1234-abc)" (RequestToken: 123-cbd-987, HandlerErrorCode: AccessDenied)
```

Here's my deployment bucket permission policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::deploymentbucket-xxxyyyzzz",
                "arn:aws:s3:::deploymentbucket-xxxyyyzzz/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, I tried to delete this bucket policy entirely and retried, it's still the same error.

My Lambda and S3 are both in the same aws account.

I tried to change Principal to be `*`, but got this error when saving:

```
Your bucket policy changes can’t be saved
You either don’t have permissions to edit the bucket policy, or your bucket policy grants a level of public access that conflicts with your Block Public Access settings. To edit a bucket policy, you need s3:PutBucketPolicy permissions. To review which Block Public Access settings are turned on, view your account and bucket settings. Learn more about Identity and access management in Amazon S3 
API response
Access Denied
```

Then I momentarily changed `Block all public access` to be `off`;
and I logged in as an admin IAM user with `AmazonS3FullAccess` permission;
retried, but still faced with the same error, cannot even save this bucket permission change.

Anyone could shed any insight please?

Thanks!

Comment: `arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:root` - are you using the root account for your CDK? And if you are - why only allowing insecure requests by setting condition of `"aws:SecureTransport": "false"`? Remove that condition and retry - it's not good whatsoever here.

Comment: I'm not sure if I was using the root account in my CDK, but I didn't find any *root* string in my CDK code, so I assumed not. But as I stated in my OP, I had removed this entire bucket permission policy and retried, still the same error if secureTransport was the issue.

Comment: OK, set principal to * and try again

Comment: Sure, I tried that before and tried it again, with results updated in my OP, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm leaving this response with the hope that it might help someone, even though I'm not sure if the issue has been resolved. I also encountered a similar error message when trying to create an S3 bucket and its policy in CloudFormation.

```
Your bucket policy changes can’t be saved
You either don’t have permissions to edit the bucket policy, or your bucket policy grants a level of public access that conflicts with your Block Public Access settings. To edit a bucket policy, you need s3:PutBucketPolicy permissions. To review which Block Public Access settings are turned on, view your account and bucket settings. Learn more about Identity and access management in Amazon S3 
API response
Access Denied
```

In my case, the cause of the error was setting the public access to "Private" in the bucket settings. Simultaneously, the bucket policy was granting access to Amazon S3 actions, resulting in a conflict. Below is the resource I attempted to create but failed.

```
Resources:
  # * Create S3 Bucket
  FilesBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Join ["-", [!Sub "${AWS::StackName}", "resources"]]
      AccessControl: Private
      CorsConfiguration:
        CorsRules:
          - AllowedHeaders:
              - "*"
            AllowedMethods:
              - GET
              - PUT
              - HEAD
            AllowedOrigins:
              - "*"
            ExposedHeaders:
              - x-amz-server-side-encryption
              - x-amz-request-id
              - x-amz-id-2
            MaxAge: 3000

  # ^ Bucket policy associations
  FilesBucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref FilesBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: "*"
            Action:
              - s3:GetObject
              - s3:PutObject
            Resource: !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${FilesBucket}/*
```

Comment: Why don't we take a look at the AWS::S3::Bucket resource you're trying to create together to help us figure out what's causing the error?

Comment: In my case, changing `AccessControl: Private` didn't resolve the issue, and I had to add the `PublicAccessBlockConfiguration` settings to fix it.